# Removing extraneous characters in column using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to remove extraneous characters from data in a primary key column..the data in this column serves as a control number, and the extra characters are preventing a Web application from effectively interacting with the data.

As an example, one row may look like this:

```
ocm03204415 820302
```

I want to remove everything after the space...so the characters '820302'.  I could manually do it, but, there are around 2,000 records that have these extra values in the column.  It would be great if I could remove them programmatically.  I can't do a simple Replace because the characters have no pattern...I couldn't define a rule to discover them...the only thing uniform is the space...although, now that I look at the data set, they do all start with 8.

Is there a way I could remove these characters programmatically?  I am familiar with PL/SQL in the Oracle environment, and was wondering if Transactional SQL would offer some possibilities in the MS-SQL environment?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look into the [`CHARINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) function to find the space.  Then you can use [`SUBSTRING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) to grab everything up to the space in a single `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourColumn = LEFT(YourColumn,CHARINDEX(' ',YourColumn)-1)
WHERE CHARINDEX(' ',YourColumn) > 1
```

Comment: Note: If this is run and some of the rows don't have spaces in this column, it will return an error (the second argument to LEFT will be -1, which isn't allowed).

Comment: @Joshua Carmody - You are absolutely right, updated my answer.